# Why is my view function running out of gas when reading from mapping/HashMap?

Tags: contract-development, evm, vyper

I have the following vyper code:

```
address_to_addresses: public(HashMap[address, address[2])
```

Vyper auto generates a `view` function called `address_to_addresses(arg0: address, arg1: uint256) -> address` that allows you to read the value of the public variable.

The abi for this function looks like this:

```
"name": "address_to_addresses",
"outputs": [
  {
    "type": "address",
    "name": ""
  }
],
"inputs": [
  {
    "type": "address",
    "name": "arg0"
  },
  {
    "type": "uint256",
    "name": "arg1"
  }
],
"stateMutability": "view",
"constant": true
```

But when I execute the following using ethersJS:

```
myContract.address_to_addresses(<someAddress>, 0)
```

I get a transaction revert error that says I have run out of gas:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas
```

How is it possible that I can be running out of gas when I am calling a `view` function? How can I call this function without "running out of gas"?

Comment: So how exactly is this question related to Solidity or web3.js?

Comment: While I'm not sure why it runs out of gas, view functions do have the same gas limitations as other functions. You cannot go over the block gas limit (which is about 12.5 million currently).

Comment: I am definitely not going above the gas limit of the block. I don't get this error when I run the code in truffle console using the truffle contract abstractions and the same local ganache instance. Other view function calls are working in EthersJS too. For example reading a public(uint256) works, but reading a public(HashMap[address, address[2]) fails.

Comment: Your function is called `addresss_to_addresses` (triple s), but you're calling `address_to_addresses` (only 2 s). Is that a typo in your question, or is that the problem?

Comment: No, that is a typo in the question. Ill update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this was a small issue with EthersJS.

The estimated gas is not input correctly. By manually defining the gas limit, it works:

```
myContract.address_to_addresses(<someAddress>, 0, { gasLimit: 60000 });
```

It's unclear why this is. If I set the gas limit to the actual cost of the function as defined in the abi (1654) then it fails - I have to set it to something quite large for it to work. So perhaps this is not an issue with EthersJS but an issue with truffle's abi generation being incorrect.

Since no gas is actually used in this transaction, again, i'm not sure why this is even needed.

Comment: This helped me out on a weird issue I was having as well. Thank you